# Nested loop on primary key

Tags: mysql, optimization, mysql-5.7

```
CREATE TABLE `request` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_by` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


explain select * from request r
left join user u on (r.created_by = u.id)

+--+-----------+-----+----------+----+-------------+----+-------+----+----+--------+--------------------------------------------------+
|id|select_type|table|partitions|type|possible_keys|key |key_len|ref |rows|filtered|Extra                                             |
+--+-----------+-----+----------+----+-------------+----+-------+----+----+--------+--------------------------------------------------+
|1 |SIMPLE     |r    |NULL      |ALL |NULL         |NULL|NULL   |NULL|2   |100     |NULL                                              |
|1 |SIMPLE     |u    |NULL      |ALL |PRIMARY      |NULL|NULL   |NULL|1   |100     |Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)|
+--+-----------+-----+----------+----+-------------+----+-------+----+----+--------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Here is the content of the tables:

```
+--+----------+-------+
|id|created_by|content|
+--+----------+-------+
|1 |NULL      |Test   |
|2 |1         |Bar baz|
+--+----------+-------+


+--+------+
|id|name  |
+--+------+
|1 |Thomas|
+--+------+
```

Why is it a nested loop ?
If I add a condition on join like this: `(r.created_by > 0 AND r.created_by = u.id)` there is no more nested loop.

My version is MySQL 5.7.34.

Comment: Probably the optimizer realizes you have so few rows in these tables, it doesn't matter. Each table fits on a single page in the database anyway, so there's no need to do any index lookups. If you had more rows, the optimizer's strategy may be different. When you are testing the query optimizer, you should create at least enough rows to make the table fill a few db pages.

Comment: I have tested with real tables and it's the same. With new condition i passed from 800ms to 50ms, so there is an impact

Comment: Try running `ANALYZE TABLE request;` and `ANALYZE TABLE user;`. Sometimes the optimizer is basing its choice on stale table statistics. It's harmless to run these statements against InnoDB tables.

Comment: Both are ok with analyze

Comment: I tested this. If I have only one row in the `user` table, I get the same results you do. If I insert a few more rows of test data in the `user` table, the join does a primary key lookup instead of block nested loop.

Comment: Is `LEFT` important?  If you remove it, the Optimizer may have more ways to perform the query.

Answer (score 0):

Most `JOIN` queries are performed via "Nested Loop Join" (NLJ).  This is where it walks through the rows of one table, and for each such row, it reaches into the next table to find the row(s) that match.

Usually this can be done via just indexes.  However, your `EXPLAIN` shows that it can improve on that with `Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)`.  This is where it loads the entire second table into a hash in memory.  This is usually (not always) faster, sometimes much faster.

As already mentioned, the number of rows is so small that you can't necessarily extrapolate to larger tables.

I see no `WHERE` clause.  Do you really want *all* rows?  When there are a million `requests`, that will be an awful lot of rows to shovel across the network to the client.

If you will have a `WHERE/GROUP/ORDER/LIMIT`, then that could radically change the Explain plan.

As for `(r.created_by > 0 AND r.created_by = u.id)` -- It sounds like
`r.created_by = u.id` belongs in the `ON` and `r.created_by > 0` belongs in the `WHERE`.  At that point, it may look for an index with `created_by` as the first column *if* it is a useful filter.

It may also transfer the `> 0` to `u.id > 0` because of the other relation.

Also, the `EXPLAIN` may have realized that all the `created_ids` were `> 0`, so it threw that out.

Or something else.  Please focus on exactly the query that will be run in production; there are too many variations.

Answer (score -1):

Nulls can be a nuisance and cause some quirky results.

The request.created_by column has a row with a null value and you are using that column to join in your select query.  You could eliminate it in the query, but I'd recommend adding a constraint so a request record cannot be created without a valid id in the users table

Comment: Likely good advice, but does it explain why a NL was chosen, which is what was asked?

Comment: Simple. the query uses joins.  MySQL executes joins between tables using a nested-loop algorithm or variations on it. Prior to MySQL 8.0.18, a Block Nested-Loop (BNL) join algorithm uses buffering of rows read in outer loops to reduce the number of times that tables in inner loops must be read algorithm was applied for equi-joins when no indexes could be used.

Comment: Cool. If you were to edit your answer to include that (which addresses the question asked) and de-emphasize the discussion of NULLs (which does not) I think that would be a good thing.